# I am trying to scrape a aspx website but unable to go beyond page2

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib, python-3.5

I am trying to scrape a aspx site : https://www.aae.org/patients/find.aspx . for testing purpose please use 33133 as zipcode & 100 as radius .

Initially I am collecting the profile links by iterating over search pages , I am successful to get first 20 links at first page but unable to go beyond page 1 , the source says - 'We\'re Sorry, the Page or File You Were Looking for Cannot be Found'

Please see my code below :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, re
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, time, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
from sys import argv

profile_links = []

def result_checker(self):
    No_results = self.xpath('//td[@colspan="3"]//p//text()')
    if "No results" in str(No_results):
        print (str(No_results).replace("['","").replace(".']","")+" for other zipcodes")
        time.sleep(10)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        pass

def Get_data(zipcode, radius):
    headers = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
                'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6',
                'Connection':'keep-alive',
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                'Host':'www.tcms.com',
                'Origin':'https://www.aae.org',
                'Referer':'https://www.aae.org/patients/find.aspx'}

    class MyOpener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
        version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17'

    myopener = MyOpener()
    url = 'https://www.aae.org/patients/find.aspx'
    f = myopener.open(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f,'lxml')
    viewstate = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
    eventvalidation = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']
    EktronClientManager = soup.select("#EktronClientManager")[0]['value']

    formData = (
        ('__EVENTVALIDATION', eventvalidation),
        ('__VIEWSTATE', viewstate),
        ('ctl00$ctl00$aaeUtilitySiteSearchWidget$tbxSiteSearch','Search'),
        ('ctl00$ctl00$cphContentTypes$cphPageContent$aaeFindEndo$ddlRadius', radius),
        ('ctl00$ctl00$cphContentTypes$cphPageContent$aaeFindEndo$txtZipCode',zipcode),
        ('EktronClientManager',EktronClientManager),
        ('ctl00$ctl00$cphContentTypes$cphPageContent$aaeFindEndo$btnFind','SEARCH'))

    encodedFields = urllib.parse.urlencode(formData)
    f1 = myopener.open(url, encodedFields)
    source = f1.read()
    target = open('sample.txt','w')
    target.write(str(source))
    target.close()
    source1 = html.fromstring(source)
    result_checker(source1)
    links = source1.xpath("//table[@class='Results']//tr//a//@href")
    for each in links:
        if "MemberID" and "AddressID" in each:
            print (each)
            profile_links.append("https://www.aae.org/patients/"+str(each))
        else:
            pass

    j = 2
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    viewstate = soup2.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
    eventvalidation = soup2.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']

    while j < 5:
        pages = 'Page$'+str(j)
        print (pages,'\n---------------')
        formData1 = (('__EVENTTARGET','ctl00$ctl00$cphContentTypes$cphPageContent$aaeFindEndo$grdResults'),
                    ('__EVENTARGUMENT',pages),
                    ('__VIEWSTATE',viewstate),
                    ('__EVENTVALIDATION',eventvalidation),
                    ('ctl00$ctl00$aaeUtilitySiteSearchWidget$tbxSiteSearch','Search'))

        encodedFields1 = urllib.parse.urlencode(formData1)
        f2 = myopener.open(url, encodedFields1)
        source2 = f2.read()
        target = open('sample.txt','w')
        target.write(str(source2))
        target.close()
        source3 = html.fromstring(source2)
        links2 = source3.xpath("//table[@class='Results']//tr//a//@href")
        for each1 in links2:
            if "MemberID" and "AddressID" in each1:
                print (each1)
                profile_links.append("https://www.aae.org/patients/"+str(each1))
            else:
                pass
        soup3 = BeautifulSoup(source2,'lxml')
        viewstate = soup3.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
        eventvalidation = soup3.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']
        j+=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Get_data('38132', 5)
    Get_data('33133', 100)
```

Comment: Any suggestions please ?

Comment: @Greg , I appreciate you edit suggestions , Could please take a look at my code & identify what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: the code is a bit long and so it's hard to find the problem rapidly. Scraping ASP.NET sites is a pain in the butt... Are you making sure that you are saving & passing your cookies between requests?

Comment: I did scraped a lot of aspx sites in past using the above method but unfortunately this time i don't  understand what going wrong . for the cookies part : I think the class MyOpener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener) will make a session [PLEASE CORRECT ME IF I AM WRONG] & hold the needed cookies across requests, The formdata such as viewstate & eventvalidation is going through each requests

Comment: At the first request for Page$1 - page does generate valid response & i able to parse 20 links, then moving to Page$2 my code is missing something (may be [authentication or formdata]) that server needs to render a valid paginated series response .

Comment: I can't find anything about FancyURLopener handling sessions/cookies. It would make sense that loading the first page works (since there are no sessions and the server has not yet sent you any cookies) but further pages would not work if you don't send back a cookie.

Comment: I see , I should use http.cookiejar instead . Thanks for you help .

Comment: Yes, it's most probably the cookies. I copied the request to find.aspx in Chrome as a cURL command and pasted it into my terminal. If I do the request with all of the form fields but without the cookies, I don't get any results.

Comment: Cheers! Let us know if that works / you can answer your own question :-) Also, you can try out [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), which might be a bit easier for projects like these (since they allow you to automate user actions instead of having to recreate the actions taken by the JavaScript code). Google around for examples of scraping in Python using these two tools.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I use Selenium for standalone programs -scraping, testing, performance evaluation , & aslo headless browsers like PhantomJS . But for this current one , i need to integrate the code to some other Django modules therefore using Urllib & Requests

Comment: Makes sense! Did the cookie jar solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Greg Sadetsky, You were absolutely right about the cookies , Creating a session then passing all POST requests with required data parameters was needed.

With the help of Requests lib , I able to create a session which stores cookies that can be used across requests .

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Request, Session
from lxml import html

def Get_data(zipcode, radius):
    All_links = []
    url = 'https://www.aae.org/patients/find.aspx'
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(url)
    #print (r.text.encode('utf-8'))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    viewstate = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
    eventvalidation = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']
    EktronClientManager = soup.select("#EktronClientManager")[0]['value']
    params = {'EktronClientManager':EktronClientManager,
              '__VIEWSTATE':viewstate,
              '__EVENTVALIDATION':eventvalidation,
              'ctl00$ctl00$aaeUtilitySiteSearchWidget$tbxSiteSearch':'Search',
              'ctl00$ctl00$cphContentTypes$cphPageContent$aaeFindEndo$ddlRadius':radius,
              'ctl00$ctl00$cphContentTypes$cphPageContent$aaeFindEndo$txtZipCode':zipcode,
              'ctl00$ctl00$cphContentTypes$cphPageContent$aaeFindEndo$btnFind':'SEARCH'}
    r2 = s.post(url,data=params)
    source = html.fromstring(r2.content)
    links = source.xpath("//table[@class='Results']//tr//a//@href")
    for each in links:
        if "MemberID" and "AddressID" in each:
            print (each)
            All_links.append("https://www.aae.org/patients/"+str(each))
    #print (r2.content)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content,'lxml')
    viewstate = soup1.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
    eventvalidation = soup1.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']
    EktronClientManager = soup1.select("#EktronClientManager")[0]['value']
    j = 2
    while j < 7:
        page = 'Page$'+str(j)
        print (page)
        params1 = {'__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$ctl00$cphContentTypes$cphPageContent$aaeFindEndo$grdResults',
                   '__EVENTARGUMENT':page,
                   'EktronClientManager':EktronClientManager,
                   '__VIEWSTATE':viewstate,
                   '__EVENTVALIDATION':eventvalidation,
                   'ctl00$ctl00$aaeUtilitySiteSearchWidget$tbxSiteSearch':'Search'}
        r3 = s.post(url,data=params1)
        source1 = html.fromstring(r3.content)
        links1 = source1.xpath("//table[@class='Results']//tr//a//@href")
        for each1 in links1:
            if "MemberID" and "AddressID" in each1:
                print (each1)
                All_links.append("https://www.aae.org/patients/"+str(each1))
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r3.content,'lxml')
        viewstate = soup2.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
        eventvalidation = soup2.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']
        EktronClientManager = soup2.select("#EktronClientManager")[0]['value']
        j+=1

Get_data(33133, 100)
```